# LINQ Query to get Column Headers in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, wcf, linq

I am working on a Silverlight application using a WCF service where I need to get all the Column Headers from a specific table.  I have been trying to write a LINQ query to do this, but so far I have not been able to get it to work correctly.  I have not found very much information pertaining to this.  I have found the following information, but I have had difficulties connecting to my data.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/4856/#ReadAndPostComment

So far I have tried the following...This will not compile due to DataContext needing a parameter and that is where I am stuck.

```
public List<string> GetColumnHeaders()
{
    DataContext context = new DataContext();
    List<string> columnList = new List<string>();
    var dataModel = context.Mapping;

    foreach (var r in dataModel.GetTables())
    {
        if (r.TableName.Equals("table1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            foreach (var c in r.RowType.DataMembers)
            {
                columnList.Add(c.MappedName);
            }
        }
    }
    return columnList;
}
```

Instead of using  `DataContext context = new DataContext();`
I tried the following, but I know the problem is the same.

```
var dataModel = new AttributeMappingSource()
                 .GetModel(
                      typeof(RepositoryBase<HBS_SondesEntities>
                 ));
```

Comment: @Nix I posted the method that is called by my service.

Comment: DataContext is a base class, so you need to plug in  **your** context.  Are you using EF? Linq2SQL ?   Where is your data coming from?

Comment: @Nix I am using EF.  I followed a Microsoft tutorial using a repository pattern, so I have a RepositoryBase class.  The code I posted was from a child class.  The RepositoryBase class is somewhat confusing for me, which may be my main problem with accessing the context.

Comment: Did you try using `HBS_SondesEntities()`  ?

Comment: @Nix I tried using HBS_SondesEntities but it did not work either.  When I get to the foreach loop the application throws a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Nix It was a variable that was set to DataContext.Mapping.

Comment: @Andrew just to make sure we are on the same page please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my best attempt at a solution, its hard to really understand what you have tried/written.

```
public List<string> GetColumnHeaders(){
  List<string> columnList = new List<string>();
  using (SondesEntities context = new HBS_SondesEntities()){
    foreach (var r in context.Mapping.GetTables()){
       if (r.TableName
             .Equals("table1", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) {

           foreach (var c in r.RowType.DataMembers){
               columnList.Add(c.MappedName);
           }
       }
     }
  }
  return columnList;
}
```

---

Assuming I didn't fat finger something here is the same code using linq.

```
public List<string> GetColumnHeaders(){

    List<string> columnList = new List<string>();
    using (SondesEntities context = new HBS_SondesEntities()){
        var query = (
           context.Mapping.GetTables()
             .Where(t=>t.TableName
                        .Equals(
                         "table1", 
                          StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        )
             ).SelectMany(x=>x.RowType.DataMembers);

        columnList  = query.Select(m=>m.MappedName).ToList()
    }
    return columnList;
}
```

Comment: I get the error: The type or namespace name 'SondesEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).  Do you know any other way I could go about this?  This was much simpler to do in Windows Form apps.

Comment: You need to add a reference to the dll/project your context was created.

Comment: Is there a way using LINQ to get the Headers without having to use Mapping?

Comment: This does work when I added LINQ to SQL data.  I was trying to avoid that so I have found a totally different way to approach the problem.  Thanks for all the help, though!

Comment: I was trying to avoid using LINQ to SQL altogether because I started running into problems due to using EF and my Repository Base class.  I had not added a LINQ to SQL class, which is why the code would not work.  When I added this, your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

http://jesseliberty.com/2009/08/13/linq-for-silverlight-developers/

I'm not sure what you mean by table, but if its a datagrid, the link should help.

Comment: I'm not trying to take the headers from the datagrid, but rather from my WCF service. By table, I mean a table from the database that was loaded into the application. In the link about, he uses a DataContext class that he wrote to use Mapping to access the column names, however I'm not entirely sure what that class should contain or how to create it.